# VB.NET Console application - Trouble using Math.Log()

Tags: vb.net, math, logarithm

I am more or less new to VB.NET and I am trying to program a simple console application for a basic finance and savings calculation program.

I am having trouble with the Math.Log() function and I hope someone can help me to point out my 
mistake/mistakes.

This is the values I need to get working (the brackets shows the values ​​that actually should work but do not in my code):

```
Public Class basicSavingsPlaner                    
    Private userTotalCost As Double                     (50,000.00)
    Private userSaves As Double                         (3,451.47)
    Private userAnnualRate As Decimal                   (0,08)
    Private userMonths As Double                        (should be 10)
```

If I use my regular calculator (TI-82) I get the correct answer of userMonths which is **10**, this is how I type it on my calculator (I switched the values from digits to the names of my Declarations):

```
(log(((userAnnualRate * userTotalCost)/userSaves)+1)/(log(1+userAnnual)) = 10.0029...
```

This is my attempt to recreate it for my VB.NET console application:

```
userMonths = ((Math.Log((userAnnualRate * userTotalCost) / userSaves) + 1) / (Math.Log(1 + userAnnualRate)))
```

In this case, userMonths's result is **14.9**, which is wrong.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me, I have search here in this forum and on Google for days now.

// Televeinken

Comment: Do you realize that Math.Log uses e as a base?

Comment: Are your parenthesis placement incorrect? You are doing the log function: Math.Log((userAnnualRate * userTotalCost) / userSaves), the +1 is added to the result of the log. Is this how it should be?

Comment: @TheShaman: Yes, the +1 has to be there. Please see my handwritten formula: [image](http://www.livna.se/Bilder/savingsformula.jpg)

Comment: The +1 should have been included in with the result of the log (not added to the result of the log) , as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the statement from your TI-82 and compare it with your VB.Net code you will see that you have the statement grouped differently between the two.  Try something like this(*note the grouping of three brackets after the initial log statement instead of two*):

```
userMonths = (Math.Log(((userAnnualRate * userTotalCost) / userSaves) + 1) / (Math.Log(1 + userAnnualRate)))
```

userMonths = 10.000008962349851

Comment: You solved it, thank you very much @Mark! 
I guess I got blind after been staring at my code for too long. Thank you again!
// Tommy

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the grouping expressions with brackets `()` that is you are executing different expressions with `Math.Log` and `log`.

if you change like this  `((Log((userAnnualRate * userTotalCost) / userSaves) + 1) / (Log(1 + userAnnualRate)))`
means it will also result in `14.9`

OR you can make a change like

```
 (Math.Log(((userAnnualRate * userTotalCost) / userSaves) + 1) / (Math.Log(1 + userAnnualRate)))
```

then both will result in `10.00`